# What's the function of "と" in "海に行きたいといつしか話した"?

Tags: grammar

It's not hard to understand the meaning of this sentence but I just want to know which function the "と" serves in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> 「海に行きたい」と、(いつしか)話した

The と is a quotative particle.